# Azure hosted website gives 404 error when domain name is preceded by www

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name, azure

*mydomain.com* works fine.
*www.mydomain.com* gives `404 - File or directory not found.`

I don't want people to use *www.mydomain.com* instead of *mydomain.com*, but I also don't want the 404 error in their face if the do.

The A record at GoDaddy looks like:
Host - Points to - TTL
@ - ip address - 600 seconds

How to fix the issue so that if user types in *www.mydomain.com* they would be magically redirected to *mydomain.com*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to have both domain names (mysite.com and www.mysite.com) explicitly set up in Azure as custom domains.

Then to use URL rewrite module in IIS (already installed in Azure) by adding *rewrite* section in the Web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="WWW Rewrite" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www[.](.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Could you expand on how this is done? "explicitly set up in Azure as custom domains"

Comment: See this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name-portal/

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is *NOT* a DNS job, you may make www as **CNAME** for *mydomain.com* but still, the www will show up in the URL

If you're using Apache2 or any webserver capable of reading and executing an .htaccess file you can use the code below :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable Rewrite Engine
# ------------------------------
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Add or remove www.  Whichever you prefer.
# This one removes which seems to be the favourable choice these days.
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I do have CNAME for www, but get the error anyway.

Comment: @Hicham, as stated in the subject, it is about Azure, which uses IIS and not Apache.

Comment: @Tom, I googled for that before giving my answer, ant nothing forces you to use **IIS** on Azure. At least, that is what I read when searching ``Azure .htaccess``

Comment: @Hicham, yes, you are right when you use, say, Linux with Apache on Azure Virtual Machines. However, *Azure hosted website* uses only IIS.

Comment: Fair enough, the OP will eventually tell us which environment he have ^^

Comment: Yes, I'm using Azure shared website, which is IIS.